# How to change Clock Text Color on WatchOS in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, watchos, watchos-8

I am trying to programatically change the Apple Watch StatusBar Clock Text Color in my WatchOS only app written in SwiftUI.

I've tried

```
.preferredColorScheme(.dark)
.preferredColorScheme(.light)
```

on `var body: some View` but that does not seem to take effect. Am I missing a step?